# VLookup analogue in VBA, printing two columns based on StrComp with common first column

Tags: vba, range, lookup

I'm updating a VBA script and trying to match a 4-digit code with a table and printing the two corresponding columns into my original sheet, plus handling codes missing from the reference table.

jobcodes = sample codes to match.
codematch = reference table, 1st column is reference codes, I want the corresponding values in columns 2 and 3 in K and L of "jobcodes".

At the minute I'm getting blank values in the first two rows, then #N/A errors in the rest of the sample table.

```
finrow3 = jobs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
jobcodes = jobs.Range(("J2"), ("L" & finrow3)).Value
codematch = stat.Range("I2:K143").Value

For i = 1 To finrow3 - 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(codematch, 1)
        If StrComp(jobcodes(i, 1), codematch(j, 1)) = 0 Then
            resulta(z, 1) = codematch(j, 2)
            resulta(z, 2) = codematch(j, 3)
        Else
            resulta(z, 1) = ""
            resulta(z, 2) = ""
        End If
    Next j
Next i

jobs.Range(("K2"), ("L" & finrow3)).Value = Application.Transpose(resulta)
```

Comment: What about `Application.VLookup` ?

Comment: Will that work with a dynamic range? That's what the finrow expression is for. A new set of records is imported every day and the length can vary.